# applying stats.linregress to every grid cell in a netcdf file

Tags: python, scipy, netcdf, python-xarray

i have a netcdf file containing the following:

`<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 65, longitude: 49, time: 7306)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 21.0 20.75 20.5 20.25 ... 5.75 5.5 5.25 5.0
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 116.0 116.25 116.5 ... 127.5 127.75 128.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1985-12-31T23:00:00 ... 2005-12-31T11:00:00
Data variables:
    pr         (time, latitude, longitude) float32 0.049636062 ... 0.6215298
    time_bnds  (time) datetime64[ns] 1985-12-31T23:00:00 ... 2005-12-31T11:00:00`

my goal is to apply stats.linregress to every grid cell of this data set
and i took the following approach:

```
from scipy import stats
import nump as np
import xarray as xr

#load data
rain = xr.load_dataset('../precipitation.1986-2005.nc')

#group by (lon,lat) pairs by:
stacked = rain.stack(paired_points=['latitude','longitude'])
grouped = stacked.groupby('paired_points').apply(stats.linregress(stacked.time.astype(float),stacked['pr']))
unstack = grouped.unstack('paired_points')
```

after application of stats.linregress i want to create a plot where every grid cell is colored by the value of the slope calculated from the linear regression.

when i run the code a `ValueError` is raised:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation 
axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 7306 and the 
array at index 1 has size 3185
```

it seems as if accessing the per-grid precipitation time series and successfully applying `stats.linregress` for each grid cell is where the problem is.

could someone suggest a way forward?

your help would be valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been resolved via:

```
rain = xr.load_dataset('../precipitation.1986-2005.nc')

def slope(x):
sl = stats.linregress(x.time.astype(float),x[dict(paired_points=0)]).slope   
return xr.DataArray(sl)
```

`#group by (lon,lat) pairs by:
stacked = rain.stack(paired_points=['latitude','longitude'])
grouped=stacked.groupby('paired_points').apply(slope)
unstack = grouped.unstack('paired_points')`

the solution above follows the 
approach taken by Dr. Ryan Abernathey in

https://gist.github.com/rabernat/bc4c6990eb20942246ce967e6c9c3dbe